# Grails findAll with sort, order, max and offset?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I want to integrate sort, order, max and offset in a findAll query. The following works fine:

```
def books = Book.findAll("from Book as b where b.approved=true order by b.dateCreated  desc", [max: max, offset: offset])
```

But what I want is:

```
def books = Book.findAll("from Book as b where b.approved=true", [sort: 'dateCreated', order: 'desc', max: max, offset: offset])
```

This does not work. How do I have to rewrite this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HQL doesn't support sort and order as parameters, so you need to include the "order by" as part of the HQL expression

```
def books = Book.findAll("from Book as b where b.approved=true"
  + " order by b.dateCreated desc", [max: max, offset: offset])
```

(or in this case just use `Book.findAllByApproved(true, [...])` instead of HQL).

So if the sort and order are variables you need a trick like

```
def books = Book.findAll("from Book as b where b.approved=true"
  + (params.sort ? " order by b.${params.sort} ${params.order}" : ''), 
  [max: max, offset: offset])
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. How can I include sort and order as variable in this query?

Comment: @userWebMobile it's a "ternary conditional" - `(condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse)` - to cope with the possibility that `params.sort` might not be set, in which case you don't need an `order by` clause at all.  If you know you will always have _some_ sort and order values then just use the `"order by b.${params.sort} ${params.order}"` bit unconditionally.

Answer (score 10):

Using "findAllBy" because it supports sort and order.

```
def results = Book.findAllByTitle("The Shining",
             [max: 10, sort: "title", order: "desc", offset: 100])
```

Click [here](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html) for details.

Answer (score 7):

Using a where query works for me:

`def books = Book.where{approved == true}.list(sort: 'dateCreated', order: 'desc', max: max, offset: offset)`

Or with params straight from the page:

`def books = Book.where{approved == true}.list(params)`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are calling fetching the list of books in a controller or a service class.

If you are calling this from a controller action, then a magic variable "params" is already available to you.
For example, if you request the page as follows

```
book/list?max=10&offset=2
```

then "params" will already have those values mapped automagically.

You can add more items to the params map as follows

```
params.sort = "dateCreated"
params.order = "desc"
```

Once you have build your params as desired, then you can use Grails dynamic query as follows

```
def books = Book.findAllByApproved(true, params)
// use "books" variable as you wish
```