# Grails GORM iterate through all hasMany elements and in general all domain class elements without reading them all in a list

Tags: grails, grails-orm, resultset

In Java, we can iterate through all rows of a table using a `ResultSet` which allows us to do so without having to fetch all rows of the table.

In Grails, we have a findAllBy... helpers. But they return a list. But what if my table rows have thousands of elements? The list may become abnormally large.

Is there anything like a `ResultSet` in Grails which allows us to iterate through elements without having to fetch them at once in a list?

Also is the same thing (i.e. ability to iterate without reading them all in a list) possible for hasMany elements of a particular domain class element?

Comment: you can use offset http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450410/grails-findall-with-sort-order-max-and-offset and iterate based on current position

Answer (score 0):

In Grails, the default implementation for GORM uses Hibernate. This default implementation does **not** have anything that behaves like `ResultSet` when loading elements for a list or association via `hasMany`.

This is one of the many limitations of Hibernate and GORM.

However, since Grails is based on Groovy/Java you do always have the option of using JDBC or Groovy SQL to work with your large collections.